# How can I give Persian stop-words to CountVectorizer as an argument?

Tags: stop-words, countvectorizer, farsi

I'm trying to use Persian stop-words for CountVectorizer() in Python (google-colaboratory).
I don't know how I should give Persian stop-words to the function as an argument

For instance, [here](https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/blob/master/hazm/data/stopwords.dat) is a Persian stop-words list yet I don't know how should I give the list to my code

```
vect = CountVectorizer(
    stop_words='persian',
    tokenizer=hazm.word_tokenize
).fit(txt)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put all of those stop words you're referring to in a python `list` and then pass the list to the `CountVectorizer`. For example:

```
persian_stop_words = ["در", "این"]
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=persian_stop_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this open-source repository to find a collection of Persian stopwords:
https://github.com/kharazi/persian-stopwords

To load them, simply just copy and paste rows in a single file (separated by new lines) and call it for example "stopwords.data". Then you can load the file in your project and put the loaded file as your CountVectorizer "stop_words" argument:

```
persian_stop_words = loadtxt('stopwords.dat', dtype=str, delimiter='\n')
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=persian_stop_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hazm library:

```
import hazm 
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=hazm.stopwords_list())
```